# What's wrong with this List expression?

Tags: f#

I have a recursive function that creates a tree like so:

```
let rec evaluate node = 
    let neighbors = getNeighbors node
    let visited = [for x, y in neighbors do
                       if not tiles.[y].[x] then
                           tiles.[y].[x] <- true
                           evaluate (x, y)]
    if List.length visited > 0 then 
        Node(x, y, visited) 
    else 
        Leaf(x, y)
```

Node and Leaf come from this definition:

```
type Tree =
    | Leaf of int * int
    | Node of int * int * Tree list
```

and `tiles` is a 2-dimensional array of booleans representing which tiles have been visited (I'm implementing maze generation).

Now the above function does not compile. The inferred type is `int*int -> unit`, when it should be `int*int -> Tree`.

I attempted to force the return type to be `Tree`, but then the compiler complains that the call to evaluate should have type `unit` but has type `Tree`.

I have found a workaround using a sequence expression and converting to list:

```
let visited = Seq.toList (seq { 
                for x, y in neighbors do
                    if not tiles.[y].[x] then
                        tiles.[y].[x] <- true
                        yield evaluate (x, y)})
```

But I don't understand why using a list expression doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just missing a yield keyword:

```
let visited = [for x, y in neighbors do
                   if not tiles.[y].[x] then
                       tiles.[y].[x] <- true
                       yield evaluate (x, y)]
```

This compiles and doesn't require forcing the return type.

Answer (score 0):

For the list expression you need to replace `do` with `->` - see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx

Also, in that case the right hand side must have a consistent type.  I would change it to

```
[for x, y in (neighbors |> List.filter (fun (x2,y2) -> not tiles.[y2].[x2])) -> ...
```

Comment: If I do that I run into similar errors. Compiler tells me the call to evaluate should return unit but returns Tree, and `visited` is inferred to be a unit list rather than Tree list.

Comment: Thanks you've put me on the right track, but to use an if statement I actually needed to use `yield`.